# Epoxide Opening with Sodium Hydride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I understand that in general, when in acidic media, the nucleophile tends to attack the more substituted side of the epoxide due to electronic reasons. And when in basic media, the nucleophile attacks the less substituted side of the epoxide due to steric reasons.

What if the hydride anion attacks an epoxide? I'd imagine the hydride anion to be quite small, and able to attack both the more substituted and less substituted sides of an asymmetric epoxide. What are the experimental results?

Also I have my doubts about hydride anion even being able to open an epoxide; I am told by Clayden that hydride anion *never* acts as a nucleophile because its 1s orbital is too small.

Comment: If I recall my organic hydride is such a poor nucleophile it won't open an epoxide or do many other organic reactions for the reason you stated.

Comment: Poor nucleophile because of its heavy solvation, right?

Comment: The hydride ion is actually gigantic. It's hard to get a reliable value because its poorly held electron cloud is very soft and deforms easily, but if I recall correctly it's theoretically the second largest common monoatomic anion known, at ~200 pm radius, losing only to iodide.

Comment: Huge because of its very poor ability to stabilize  electron density, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in acidic media, the nucleophile tends to attack the more substituted side of the epoxide due to electronic reasons

This is an $\ce{S_{N}1}$ like reaction. First we would protonate the epoxide oxygen.  If we examine the case of an unsymmetrical epoxide and draw the resonance structures for this situation (see below) we would expect the secondary carbocation structure to count more towards the actual structure than the primary carbocation structure.  Therefore, we would expect a nucleophile to react preferentially at the tertiary epoxide carbon, quite selectively.

[image]

> in basic media, the nucleophile attacks the less substituted side of
>   the epoxide due to steric reasons.

This would be a traditional $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction.  Attack at the least substituted (sterically most accessible) carbon would be expected.

> What if the hydride anion attacks an epoxide? I'd imagine the hydride
>   anion to be quite small, and able to attack both the more substituted
>   and less substituted sides of an asymmetric epoxide. What are the
>   experimental results?

The hydride anion is not free, but complexed, so it has reasonable steric bulk - enough for stereoselective reactions to occur.   Further, the reaction between LAH and epoxides is quite facile, no doubt accelerated by the release of steric strain in the 3-membered epoxide ring system. A traditional $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction takes place.  In the figure below, the alcohol shown is formed in *ca*. 90% yield.  Because of the "backside" attack nature of the $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction axial attack is strongly preferred in cyclic systems.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. My professor commented that the hydride anion was so small that the opening of the epoxide _is not_ stereoselective.

Comment: "Lithium aluminum hydride usually delivers hydride with excellent selectivity to the less substituted carbon of an epoxide", see page 358,  http://www.wavefun.com/products/books/Chapter4.pdf    a few more examples showing high stereoselectivity in http://depts.washington.edu/chemcrs/bulkdisk/chem531A_win06/notes_Epoxide_opening.pdf

Comment: I was thinking of sodium hydride; would that be the same thing?

Comment: No, each form of hydride  ($\ce{LiAlH_4, NaBH_4, NaH}$, etc.) has noticeably different properties.

Comment: Oh okay. I was referring to NaH exclusively.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed that.

Comment: It's okay at least I gleaned a lot about the nature of LAH!

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/156054/can-nah-open-the-epoxide-ring-to-form-alcohol-if-so-how

Answer (score 0):

There's much detail to it beyond the scope and nit necessary but the final result is:

1. Bases (or ions with negative charge) attack the sterically unhindered positions
2. Acid catalyzed ring opening happens from the position best to stabalize positive charge even though it doesn't form