# Can NaH open the epoxide ring to form alcohol? If so, how?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

I was looking at the organic chemistry 8th Ed textbook by Paula Yurknais Brucie. On page 509, I found this:

[image]

I think about it for a while and I am doubting that it is wrong. I believe the hydride ion itself cannot act as a nucleophile for S<sub>N</sub>2. (not really sure but I guess it is too small and too basic to work as a nucleophile, it should be much easier to attack hydrogen rather than carbon for hydride ion)

Is this reaction is possible with $\ce{NaH}$ in solvents other than water and alcohol? If so, how does the hydride ion open the epoxide ring? (hoping for an answer with mechanism)

And I am specifically talking about hydride ion (or hydrogen anion). Not sodium borohydride $\ce{NaBH4}$, lithium aluminum hydride $\ce{LiAlH4}$, or other metal hydrides.

Comment: Well, there's no proton acidic enough, so it's gonna open the ring.

Comment: Going to have to be in aprotic solvent. NaH reacts vigourously with alcohols and water

Comment: I have been looking for this reaction and I find no examples. Nor in my limited experience of 40+ years can I ever recall seeing sodium hydride used as a source of nucleophilic hydride without some modifying agent (such as this example https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403900986313). Perhaps someone who has better database access than I can find it.

Comment: @Mithoron I don't think so. It is going to sit there and do nothing until it is worked up.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15186/epoxide-opening-with-sodium-hydride). It has a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne  the answer you refer to concerns LiAlH4 opening of epoxides. It specifically excludes any reference to NaH even though the OP asked about NaH.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Further to my comments above, I am going to offer my opinion that the book is wrong and the epoxide is not opened by sodium hydride as depicted. I have failed to find any literature examples of such a reaction and, in 40+ years as a synthetic chemist, I can recall no reactions in which $\ce{NaH}$, unmodified by other reagents, acts as a source of nucleophilic $\ce{H-}$.

Can anyone produce a literature example?

Comment: @user55119 do you know of any examples?

Comment: I was as nonplussed as you when I saw this reaction of "naked" NaH. In my 40++ years I have not seen such a transformation. My Chem. Absts. search turned up only the reference in your Comment (DOI:10.1016/S0040-4039(00)98631-3). Textbooks are invariably riddled with errors and omissions.

Comment: Apropos of my final remark above, I once used a textbook that interpreted in great detail the fragmentation pattern of the EI mass spectrum of methyl propyl ether. Only one problem. The spectrum was that of diethyl ether!

Comment: @Waylander, maybe the textbook is incorrect and just makes up this reaction out of nowhere. I also cannot found any example in the literature. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Kicked it around this evening at the pub with a synthetic chemistry colleague of similar experience - he also thinks this reaction will not occur.